# InstaSharper Token

Tags: c#, instagram

I am trying to learn how to use **InstaSharper** but I've got a problem. Everytime when I run my code to see the new code working, I have to login, but if I do this too many times, I will be blocked by Instagram. I was blocked on two accounts allready. So I need a solution not to always have to login like a token or something.

My login:

```
public static async void Login()
        {
            api = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
                                 .SetUser(user)
                                 .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions))
                                 .SetRequestDelay(RequestDelay.FromSeconds(5, 10))
                                 .Build();
            var loginRequest = await api.LoginAsync();
            if (loginRequest.Succeeded)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login In Success!");
                Follow("artofbokeh");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Login Failed");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can save your state in a a file and load it again.

Please give this piece of code a try, it is taken form the official github repo which can be found under this link: [Github repo](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper/blob/master/InstaSharper.Examples/Program.cs)

```
            // create user session data and provide login details
            var userSession = new UserSessionData
            {
                UserName = "username",
                Password =  "password"
            };

            // create new InstaApi instance using Builder
            _instaApi = InstaApiBuilder.CreateBuilder()
                .SetUser(userSession)
                .UseLogger(new DebugLogger(LogLevel.Exceptions)) // use logger for requests and debug messages
                .SetRequestDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2))
                .Build();

            const string stateFile = "state.bin";
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(stateFile))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Loading state from file");
                    Stream fs = File.OpenRead(stateFile);
                    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    _instaApi.LoadStateDataFromStream(fs);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            if (!_instaApi.IsUserAuthenticated)
            {
                // login
                Console.WriteLine($"Logging in as {userSession.UserName}");
                var logInResult = await _instaApi.LoginAsync();
                if (!logInResult.Succeeded)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Unable to login: {logInResult.Info.Message}");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            var state = _instaApi.GetStateDataAsStream();
            using (var fileStream = File.Create(stateFile))
            {
                state.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                state.CopyTo(fileStream);
            }
```

Edit the function to get the state data does the following:

```
public Stream GetStateDataAsStream()
        {
            var state = new StateData
            {
                DeviceInfo = _deviceInfo,
                IsAuthenticated = IsUserAuthenticated,
                UserSession = _user,
                Cookies = _httpRequestProcessor.HttpHandler.CookieContainer
            };
            return SerializationHelper.SerializeToStream(state);
        }
```

So yes you save all needed information to not login everytime. If this doesnt work for you you are doing something wrong. Please post your code where you load / save the state file.

Comment: Even if I have state saved in that file, I am still not authenticated so I have to login everytime.

Comment: I need something to remain authenticated, not to login everytime.

Comment: Check my edit @AdiBârsan please edit your question. Your code probably contains some errors.